# SSMS Import/Export tool doesn't have option to choose database

Tags: ssms

there;
I am using SSMS version V18.5.1, having problem using Import/Export tool:
There is no option to choose a database after I put a SQL server name.

THX for the TIP!

I am using "SQL Server native Client 11.0" to import data from same/different SQL server (same issue), in "Choose a data source", there is no option to choose a database (I can confirm it is the right server name):
[image: choose data source screen when importing data]

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: Please post more details: which steps are you following? Which Data source are you using? Can you add a screenshot of the window with the missing database selection?

Comment: THX Andrea for the response. I cannot connect to the server for now. I will add more detail once the server is ready. Cheers

Comment: I found what the problem is. It's my "small" screen size hides the "database" option! This is my new laptop which is 15 inches!